# How do you distinguish between 2 has_many relationships one polymorphic, one a foreign_key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm implementing an Activity Feed with a table that has
two different association to a User.
1. a polymorphic association called notifiable to a user because a user can be the target of an event say a user following another user
2. A belongs_to association to User who is the recipient of the activity and will see it in their feed.

**How do you distinguish the two different has_many activities associations?**

When I call user.activities it does use the association i want which is the user_id, but, is there a way to explicitly give it a name?

```
class CreateActivities < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
 def change
   create_table :activities do |t|
   t.references  :user, foreign_key: true, index: true
   t.references  :notifiable, polymorphic: true, index: true
 end
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :activities, as: :notifiable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :activities, foreign_key: "user_id"
end

class Activity < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :notifiable, polymorphic: true
 belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can give custom name and provide class name so that rails can understand what association to look for

```
  has_many :some_random_name, class:"Activity", foreign_key: "user_id"
```